# Logistic regression - are interaction terms redundant vs original features if using L1 penalization for feature selection?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, lasso, regularization, multicollinearity

I am running lasso/elastic regression for feature selection in a logistic classifier. I have two continuous features, and was wondering if it would be redundant to include an interaction term or other feature created from the two (like a product x*y or ratio x/y)?

I am assuming that the ratio would run into multicollinearity against the two original features, but from what I know logistic regression is linear and additive.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! If you’re using regularization, why do you want to select features? Why not use all of them?

Comment: @Dave is right.  I you insist on feature selection make sure you respect the hierarchy principal.  Rob Tibshirani and colleagues have developed lasso methods that only allow interactions in both main effects are "selected".

Comment: @Dave I think I caused some confusion with my wording. To my understanding lasso regression will enforce feature sparsity and drive the coefficient of redundant/collinear features toward 0. The original rationale of my question lies more around is it meaningful to create a feature (such as a ratio of two existing features) if I'm using lasso logistic regression?